# Suitable alternative for ddply function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

How can I convert the following tibble to the final result posted below using dplyr?

```
> group_by(hth, team) %>% arrange(team)
Source: local data frame [26 x 14]
Groups: team [13]

    team   CSK    DC    DD    GL   KKR   KTK  KXIP    MI    PW   RCB  RPSG
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    CSK     0     8    11     0    11     2     9    10     4    10     0
2    CSK     0     2     5     0     5     0     8    12     2     9     0
3     DC     2     0     8     0     2     1     7     5     3     8     0
4     DC     8     0     3     0     7     0     3     5     1     3     0
5     DD     5     3     0     0     7     2     8     5     2    10     2
6     DD    11     8     0     2    10     0    10    13     4     7     0
7     GL     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
8     GL     0     0     0     0     2     0     2     2     0     2     2
9    KKR     5     7    10     2     0     0     5    10     3    15     0
10   KKR    11     2     7     0     0     2    14     8     2     3     2
# ... with 16 more rows, and 2 more variables: RR <dbl>, SH <dbl>
>
```

I used plyr's ddply function and was able to achieve the result.

```
> ddply(hth, .(team), function(x) colSums(x[,-1], na.rm = TRUE))
   team CSK DC DD GL KKR KTK KXIP MI PW RCB RPSG RR SH
1   CSK   0 10 16  0  16   2   17 22  6  19    0 17  6
2    DC  10  0 11  0   9   1   10 10  4  11    0  9  0
3    DD  16 11  0  2  17   2   18 18  6  17    2 16  8
4    GL   0  0  2  0   2   0    2  2  0   3    2  0  3
5   KKR  16  9 17  2   0   2   19 18  5  18    2 15  9
6   KTK   2  1  2  0   2   0    1  1  1   2    0  2  0
7  KXIP  17 10 18  2  19   1    0 18  6  18    2 15  8
8    MI  22 10 18  2  18   1   18  0  6  19    2 16  8
9    PW   6  4  6  0   5   1    6  6  0   5    0  5  2
10  RCB  19 11 17  3  18   2   18 19  5   0    2 16  9
11 RPSG   0  0  2  2   2   0    2  2  0   2    0  0  2
12   RR  17  9 16  0  15   2   15 16  5  16    0  0  7
13   SH   6  0  8  3   9   0    8  8  2   9    2  7  0
>
```

How to achieve the same using just dplyr functions?

Comment: `group_by(hth, team) %>% summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Thank you. The code worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are grouping by `team` and summing the columns, in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

hth %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :). Thank you

Comment: @AnirudhMurali No problem, and welcome to StackOverflow! If the answer helped you with your problem be sure to accept it to let others know it worked (click the checkmark to the left).